# Connecting Bot with Emulator

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm trying to program a bot, which can book rooms. Problem is the emulator can't reach the bot. I'm using the url https://localhost:44378/api/messages as an endpoint. The emulator shows the message:" request … failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate". Strange thing is, when i go to the site on Internet Explorer, it says i have a valid certificate. I know the program works. I am using IIS express and the program should be using a self signed certificate for HTTPS. Any ideas ?

Comment: I rarely ask this, but can you post the whole error?

Comment: request to https://localhost:44378/api/messages failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate. That's all. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a member of the emulator team, it's an underlying issue with the emulator:

> We are not likely to fix this since it may introduce security vulnerabilities and non-ssl alternatives exist. If you must run your bot locally using SSL, please consider using a free CA like https://letsencrypt.org/